# Create a file with cmis rest service

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, rest, cmis

I'm working on a POC and I need to create a file using the cmis protocol of SharePoint but I don't know how to do it. I've activated the CMIS feature and I'm already able to get a fileContentStream or a simple cmis query. 
The problem is that I don't find information about the creation of a file using rest cmis.
It seems that this service does not exist:

http://server/subsite/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/repo_id?createDocument

Comment: Check [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff934619.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Especially for spcmis.wsp existence. Also you should use the following format: https://server/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/46852CAA-B640-41E4-A897-5862EA425CCD?getRepositoryInfo, where %GUID% is a guid of document library (repository).

Comment: I'm on SharePoint 2013 and the consumer webpart has been removed. The feature is already activated, and I'm already able to retrieve SharePoint stored document information. The problem is to create a file from the outside with a rest request to the cmis.

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible. Take a look [here](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/content-management-interoperability-services-cmis-in-sharepoint).
>**CMIS does not provide methods for creating, modifying, or deleting
object-types.** Developers who want to create, modify, or delete a
SharePoint Server document object-type or folder object-type can do so by using the proprietary SharePoint Server object model. If you check output, e,g, 
https://server/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/GUID?getRepositoryInfo you'll find that there are no "createDocument" entries.

Comment: I am sure this is doable (*for example my tool CmisSync can create documents using CMIS REST*). To know the URL syntax, connect to your server using CMIS Workbench, and create a document via the user interface while listening to netowrk traffic using Wireshark.

Comment: Is there something to configure to use CMIS Workbench? I've tried to connect but it always say that my credential are not good.

Comment: It depends on your auth settings. I've tried with NTLM selected (not Standard) and it works good, i.e. with endpoint https://server/_vti_bin/cmis/rest?getRepositories. However for sites with SAML (ADFS) auth i was unable to connect.

Comment: I'm connected to the repositories but I can't create a document. I have an error message that told me that I'm unauthorized. But I'm connected with the admin of the collection site.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue. I was able to connect to repo (library) and create a file. However the only error i had was when the wrong CT was chosen.

Comment: I think it was just a bug, everything work. I was able to find the xml to pass with wireshark. Thanks everybody!